# How to iterate over XML children with same name as current element and avoid current element in iteration?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

#### I have

A given XML (can't change naming) that have same name for a node and its direct children, here `items`

#### I want

To iterate on the children only, the `items` that have a `description` field

#### My issue

The parent node of type `items` appears in the iteration, even the `iter` is called on itself if I understand well

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree
content = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <items>
        <items>
            <description>foo1</description>
        </items>
        <items>
            <description>foo2</description>
        </items>
    </items>
</root>
"""
tree = ElementTree.fromstring(content)
print(">>", tree.find("items"))
for item in tree.find("items").iter("items"):
    print(item, item.find("description"))
```

Current output

```
>> <Element 'items' at 0x0000020B5CBF8720>
<Element 'items' at 0x0000020B5CBF8720> None
<Element 'items' at 0x0000020B5CBF8770> <Element 'description' at 0x0000020B5CBF87C0>
<Element 'items' at 0x0000020B5CBF8810> <Element 'description' at 0x0000020B5CBF8860>
```

Expected output

```
>> <Element 'items' at 0x0000020B5CBF8720>
<Element 'items' at 0x0000020B5CBF8770> <Element 'description' at 0x0000020B5CBF87C0>
<Element 'items' at 0x0000020B5CBF8810> <Element 'description' at 0x0000020B5CBF8860>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XPath with findall().

```
tree.findall('items/items')
```